# Trying to implement a grid view with a one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, wice-grid

`Image` has a `one-to-many` association with `Category`:

```
# Category model:
has_many :images
# Image model:
has_one :category
# Images migration file:
t.references :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

I'm trying to implement a grid view using the [wice_grid gem](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid). This works but one line is failing. The following works in the index view:

```
g.column name: 'Category', attribute: 'category_id', auto_reload: true, html: {id: 'grid-cells'} do |image|
  image.category_id
end
```

But this displays the number/id of the category, while I want it to display its name. If I try `image.category` instead of `image.category_id` there's an error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column categories.image_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."image_id...
```

How can I have it display the category name instead of the id of the category?

Controller method:

```
def index
  @images_grid = initialize_grid(Image,
  # include: :category  # Do I need this? Tried it with and without
  per_page: 40)
end
```

---

**Update:** After correcting the association and using in the view the code below, it works. Except for the filter function for this specific column. If I enter text to filter on, it reloads the table, but without applying the filter (all records are still displayed).

```
g.column name: 'Category', attribute: 'category_id', auto_reload: true, html: {id: 'grid-cells'} do |image|
  image.category.category unless image.category.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image model you should have `belongs_to :category`, not `has_one`. The association is the n-1, not 1-1.

On the second part of your problem - filtering the items by category name, I believe you need to use a custom filter:

```
g.column name: 'Category', attribute: 'images.category_id',
      custom_filter: Category.find(:all).map{|cat| [cat.id, cat.name]} do |image|
  image.category.name if image.category
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, filtering on this specific column doesn't work. If I enter text in the filter field, it reloads the table but still with all records. Any idea how to get that working? (sorting does work for the column)

Comment: I've updated with a potential way that you can handle the filter.

Comment: Thanks @stef. Upon loading the page it produces the error `Couldn't find Category with 'id'=all`. If I change `find(:all)` to `.all`, I get the error `WiceGrid: Invalid attribute name images.category_id. An attribute name must not contain a table name!`.

Comment: I had success with the following: `g.column name: 'Category', model: 'Category', attribute: 'name', auto_reload: true, html: {id: 'grid-cells'} do |image|`  `image.category.name if image.category`  `end`. While including `include: :category` in the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

The other side of a `has_many` is a `belongs_to`.  You need the image model to say:

```
belongs_to :category
```

The mnemonic I use to remember which is which is the "person and dog":  A person `has_many` dogs, and a dog `belongs_to` an owner.  Which one wears the "id_tag" on their collar?  The dog.  So the id column goes on the `belongs_to` model.

Answer (score 0):

It has many categories so you should do something like

```
image.categories.find(:id)
```

You need to get provide id for category as query image.categories will return a collection array of all the categories for the image

Comment: I belief I have modeled it correctly so that an image has 1 category... In the Image model I have: `has_one :category`